# ASP.NET and HTTP 404 problem (IIS problem)

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

net webforms application which is a new version of an old webshop. I have a lot of inbound links from the Internet, that point to a particular category page: http://www.example.com/category1.html, the path to this category in the new setup is similar to: http://www.example.com/category.aspx?id=42.

I have setup the Category.aspx page to handle errors and redirect to a custom page, log the error and redirect to my front page.

I have setup the Global.asax Application_Error to do the same

I have setup the Web.config, with custom errors to relay 404 using the same concept as above.

Everything is working as it should in Visual Studio (the build in web server), when i publish it to my web host, it doesn't work, they say it is running in integrated mode... anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: And if you want to access just category.aspx does it work? Does it log any error? Is HTTP 404 based on your redirection or is it fired by IIS? The web application in IIS can be incorrectly configured so that http://www.example.com/... doesn't point to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS running in Integrated mode, so i finally found out that i couldnt handle this the way i did, i write a httphandler, registered it in the web.config and assigned it to intercept all calls made to *.html files. All i had to do was then to rediret to the proper source page.

Answer (score 1):

With the build-in webserver, every request is handled as if it were an asp.net page, so your web.config is always used in that case.

In IIS however, .html is not handled by asp.net but by the static file handler, so the web.config is ignored (altough IIS7 looks at the web.config for some stuff, but that's not relevant for your problem)

So you need to either have .html handled by asp.net (set the .html extension to be handled by the same dll as the .aspx pages in IIS) or you should set the error-page in IIS (and not in your web.config).